# Why doesn't a cloned theme work as the original theme?

Tags: 7

I've cloned a theme, by duplicating and renaming it, in /sites/all/themes/. When I switch to the new theme, portions of the theme, a slideshow, don't work.

It looks like `views_get_view_result()` in template.php is not returning anything. Is there some configuration I need to set up per theme?

I'm new to Drupal and I am helping out a friend. The site is using Drupal 7.

Comment: where you have written the `views_get_view_result()` in template.php. also make sure the name of your theme is properly replaced wherever required

Comment: Can you clarify where the name of the theme is to be replaced? If I have a function call `theme_preprocess_page` should that be renamed `theme_clone_preprocess_page`?

Comment: If the original theme was named `theme`, and the new one is named `theme_clone`, then yes, exactly that. Also make sure you've updated the .info filename

Comment: Depending on which user you used for the "*I've cloned a theme*", it could also be a file permission issue ...

Answer (score 0):

In `template.php` the functions that begin with the template name e.g. `themename_preprocess_page` need to be renamed to have the new theme name in them e.g. `newthemename_preprocess_page`.